# How can I remove the white space between two tables?

Tags: html, css

I know this is a very simple question, but I somehow don't get it to work. I looked at many other questions here, but couldn't find the right answer.

How can I remove white space between two tables without setting a negative margin? I've tried the following things on the table and body without any luck:

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:block;
```

Here's a fiddle to test it out: http://jsfiddle.net/sznurkqo/

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/5cs4xx20/)**

In your case, `.table` is having `margin-bottom:20px` that's why there is a space.

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

remove that space and it will work.

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome :) please accept as answer if it has solved the problem

Comment: I did now! :) Thanks. Didn't know how to before.

Answer (score 0):

I found in my case that

margin-bottom:-15px;

did the job.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35254624)